# Could not do normal boot. Invalid kernel

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing

I actually don't know what happened to my dad's phone but I cannot get pass the Samsung logo. It shows a text in red saying ***Could not do normal boot. INVALID KERNEL***.
I downloaded a new firmware from Sammobile.com and tried to flash but I get fails. I could really use a help. Images uploaded.[image: when trying to turn on phone, this is shows]

this is what shows when I tried to flash a new firmware *(SM-A105F_XSG_A105FDDS6BUB1_A105FOJM6BUB1_A105FDDS6BUB1_A105FDDS6BUB1.zip)* on it using Odin.

```
  <OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/013> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/013> Odin engine v(ID:3.1203)..
<ID:0/013> File analysis..
<ID:0/013> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/013> Can't open the serial(COM) port.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

Comment: try another cable or usb 2.0 hub

Comment: I'll get a get a new cable tomorrow and try again. Thanks @alecxs